# Ellipsize text that is between two other texts without flexing trailing text to end

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I have a view that has `flexDirection: 'row'` that will contain 3 text elements. I want the text elements to flow one after the other, but in the case that space is limited, I want the middle text element to be the one that is ellipsized.

Ex. where | is the edge of the screen

`| John Smith johnsmith@test.com 9/24/19        |`

but if the device is small

`| John Smith johnsmith@t.. 9/24/19 |`

A solution related to a different question suggested putting the middle text inside a view with flex: 1, which does cause the middle text to be the ellipsized text (when I also indicate the numberOfLines and ellipsizeMode properties) but that causes the trailing text to be pushed to the end, like the following

`| John Smith johnsmith@test.com         9/24/19|`

which I don't want.

Here is a snack with the code

https://snack.expo.io/Sk6_MldDH

Or here is an example component

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      // If space is tight, I want the middle text ellipsized 

      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: 250, borderWidth: 1}}>
       <Text>John Smith</Text>
       <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <Text ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={1} style={{ color: 'gray', marginHorizontal: 8}}>johnsmith@test.com</Text>
       </View>
       <Text style={{ color: 'gray'}}>9/24/19</Text>
       </View>

      // If plenty of space, I want the date to immediately follow the email, not have it pushed to the end

      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: 350, borderWidth: 1}}>
       <Text>John Smith</Text>
       <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <Text ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={1} style={{ color: 'gray', marginHorizontal: 8}}>johnsmith@test.com</Text>
       </View>
       <Text style={{ color: 'gray'}}>9/24/19</Text>
       </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you set the date to have the `flex: 1` instead of the email?

Comment: It appears to have the same effect as `flex: 1` on the parent view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snack with my solution: https://snack.expo.io/rkEncIYvS

Within the `View`:

```js
<Text ellipsizeMode='tail' numberOfLines={1}>John Smith <Text style={{ color: 'gray', marginHorizontal: 8}}>johnsmith@test.com</Text></Text>
<Text style={{ color: 'gray', flex: 1}}>9/24/19</Text>
```

I could not find a way to keep the name and email separate without the name overflowing into the next line.

However, with nested `Text` components, you can achieve a similar result.

Setting `flex: 1` on the date ensures that the date `Text` component will attempt to fill the remaining space.